# How can I determine whether a specific file is open in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, filesystems

One of my favourite tools for linux is [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) - a real swiss army knife!

Today I found myself wondering which programs on a WinXP system had a specific file open. Is there any equivalent utility to lsof? Additionally, the file in question was over a network share so I'm not sure if that complicates matters.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from the Sysinternals Suite, the Find Handle or DLL function will let you search for the process with that file open.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? Process Explorer lets you see which files are open for a particular process/handle/dll/whatever, but that's the reverse mapping. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/lsof-equivalent-for-windows#188337 to this question.

Comment: Yes it does.  Click on Find Handle or Dll (or hit Ctrl-F) , type in the name of the file you are searching for, and you end up with a list of processes with that file open.

Comment: Process Explorer has now been renamed and bundled into "Process Monitor".

Comment: @MatthewMcCullough Any references? You are incorrect, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) are two different utilities.

Comment: Does Process Explorer have a command-line interface?

Comment: This was so awesome. I knew about Process Explorer but not the ^F trick, and it just helped me track a bug where my application could not delete its own lock file. (The culprit was "Immunet 3.0 Agent", free antivirus software that is apparently worth every penny.)

I really don't understand the obsession with marking tips like this "off topic". Programmers need tools.

Comment: @MatthewMcCullough Correction. FileMon and RegMon are now bundled into [Process Monitor v3.2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on versions of Windows starting with Windows 2000 SP4, Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 SP1, and Windows Vista.

Comment: It's working, but very slow. It takes more than 5 minutes to find that on my computer.

Comment: It appears on the process explorer web page there is a link to a command line utility "handle" to do this on the command line.

Answer (score 50):

The equivalent of `lsof -p pid` is the combined output from sysinternals handle and listdlls, ie

```
handle -p pid
listdlls -p pid
```

you can find out pid with sysinternals `pslist`.

Comment: Does this come with a standard windows installation like Windows 10?

Comment: @Morten sysinternals is an external Microsoft package that "every" windows developer installs, but it does not come with the box. but they are small and easily shipped with your application (we do something like that to install our java application as a windows service).

Answer (score 11):

Try [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).  [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) & [Regmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) are also great for trying to figure out what the duce program foo is doing to your system.

Comment: @slipsec FileMon and Regmon are now replaced by [Process Monitor v3.2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)  on versions of Windows starting with Windows 2000 SP4, Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 SP1, and Windows Vista.

Comment: Thanks, Process Explorer for some reason does not find the handle, but the handle64 does, very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

One equivalent of *lsof* could be combined output from Sysinternals' *handle* and *listdlls*, i.e.:

```
c:\SysInternals>handle
[...]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gvim.exe pid: 5380 FOO\alois.mahdal
   10: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows
   1C: File  (RW-)   D:\some\locked\path\OpenFile.txt
[...]

c:\SysInternals>listdlls
[...]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Listdlls.exe pid: 6840
Command line: listdlls

  Base        Size      Version         Path
  0x00400000  0x29000   2.25.0000.0000  D:\opt\SysinternalsSuite\Listdlls.exe
  0x76ed0000  0x180000  6.01.7601.17725  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
[...]

c:\SysInternals>listdlls
```

Unfortunately, you have to "run as Administrator" to be able to  use them.

Also *listdlls* and *handle* do not produce continuous table-like form so filtering filename would hide PID. `findstr /c:pid: /c:<filename>` should get you very close with both utilities, though

```
c:\SysinternalsSuite>handle | findstr /c:pid: /c:Driver.pm
System pid: 4 \<unable to open process>
smss.exe pid: 308 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
avgrsa.exe pid: 384 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
[...]
cmd.exe pid: 7140 FOO\alois.mahdal
conhost.exe pid: 1212 FOO\alois.mahdal
gvim.exe pid: 3408 FOO\alois.mahdal
  188: File  (RW-)   D:\some\locked\path\OpenFile.txt
taskmgr.exe pid: 6016 FOO\alois.mahdal
[...]
```

Here we can see that gvim.exe is the one having this file open.

Answer (score 6):

Try [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).

The Unlocker site has a nifty chart (scroll down after following the link) that shows a comparison to other tools. Obviously such comparisons are usually biased since they are typically written by the tool author, but the chart at least lists the alternatives so that you can try them for yourself.

Comment: Unlocker only lists locked files, not opened files. Most Windows software locks the DLL it uses but not your documents.

Comment: Anyone has comparison between it and http://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php please?

Answer (score 6):

If the file is a .dll then you can use the **TaskList** command line app to see whose got it open:

```
TaskList /M nameof.dll
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a program "OpenFiles", seems to be part of windows 7. Seems that it can do what you want. It can list files opened by remote users (through file share) and, after calling 
"openfiles /Local on" and a system restart, it should be able to show files opened locally. The latter is said to have performance penalties.

Comment: I come here looking for a way to find out who's preventing me from deleting a folder and avoid a restart, and I find the command I need requires a config setup that ... you guessed it.... requires  a restart. How very very windows.

Comment: folks, be aware that the openfiles command takes a LONG time to run (on the order of 4 minutes)!

Answer (score 3):

Use Process Explorer to find the process id. Then use [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to find out what files are open.

Eg handle -p

I like this approach because you are using utilities from Microsoft itself.

Comment: if only we had source code to those

Answer (score 2):

In [OpenedFilesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html), under the Options menu, there is a menu item named "Show Network Files".  Perhaps with that enabled, the aforementioned utility is of some use.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on your "Computer" (or "My Computer") icon and select "Manage" from the pop-up menu, that'll take you to the Computer Management console.

In there, under System Tools\Shared Folders, you'll find "Open Files". This is probably close to what you want, but if the file is on a network share then you'd need to do the same thing on the server on which the file lives.

Comment: Note that this only shows shared files that are open by other network users.  It doesn't help find files that are open on the local system.  Doing this on the server would probably tell you which user had the file open, but not which program on that user's machine.  Process Explorer (as mentioned by @JayHofacker) worked well for me.