# Identify process using a file

Tags: windows, winapi, wmi

I have been trying to figure out how to programmatically identify the process that has a lock on a particular file.  I've searched through the Win32 API and WMI, but so far I can't find anything.  I know it's possible - Sysinternals is able to list every resource accessed/locked by every process on the system.

Can anyone drop me a hint?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [handle.exe from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655).

Something like:

```
> handle /accepteula C:\path\to\directory
...
program.exe           pid: 1234   type: File           2E4: C:\path\to\directory
...
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/599268/367916 .

Answer (score 14):

You could use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/processexplorer) from Microsoft

1. Download & unpack & run **Process Explorer**
2. Click **Find** menu and then click **Find Handle or DLL...** or press **CTRL + F**
3. Copy and paste path to locked folder of file
4. Click **Search**, you can kill process from main **Process Explorer** window

Answer (score 4):

If you can limit yourself to new enough versions of Windows, the Restart Manager can tell you [which process has a particular file open](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx).

Comment: @MichaelBest Search the link in the Wayback Machine to get a nicely formatted result, or to see the migrated version [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283).

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way Process Explorer works, I suspect that what you need to look for is a way of finding the file handles attached to a given process, and that you'll have to pull that list for each process in the system and look for your file within it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in Windows, but somebody might find useful to know that, in Linux, you can use the *lsof* command, or just search through the folders /proc/PROCESS_ID/fd and see what process has opened the file.

Comment: On Linux this is not much of a problem since inodes are refcounted, so you can remove a file even if someone is holding it open.

Answer (score 0):

[WhoLockMe](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) is a nice right click windows explorer extension.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/article.php/c2893) might be helpful to you.

It appears you are forced to search through the list of files for each process on the system using undocumented functions in ntdll.dll.

Comment: "404 Page Not Found"