# Windows CMD: Determine which application is using a file

Tags: windows, cmd, malware

This isn't really a programming question...
Are there any ways to determine which application is currently using a file? I've been infected with one of those autorun.inf viruses. When I try to delete the autorun.inf Windows tells me the files is in use by another application (obviously, the virus).

Can I find out which application is using the file? I'd probably be easier to just grab a free antivirus but I'd like to first try and remove the malware myself before I try anything else (could be useful knowledge).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identify process using a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379689/identify-process-using-a-file)

Comment: @Paul: read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), paragraph: how do I ask questions, last part.

Comment: It's how often you have accepted an answer on your question (i.e. clicked the checkmark so it turned green)

Comment: @David Hefernan: this comment is a bit rude IMO. Many newcomers here are not aware of the accept system.

Comment: @Benoit Message seems to have been received. Also, I said declined with "no thanks" which is polite in my circles!! I should have pointed Paul at the FAQ though. Thanks for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sysinternals' Process Explorer or Process Monitor to do that.