# Python::Identify PID on Port

Tags: python, process, subprocess, port

I want to make a script, that will

1. Determine which ports are running.
2. Kill the process running on the port, will take a port number as an argument.

I completed the first task, but the 2nd task has some problems. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874481/in-python-is-there-a-cross-platform-way-of-determining-what-process-is-listening?rq=1) suggests that `lsof` is not cross-platform making this problem somewhat **impossible** to solve.

I then tried using `netstat -b` from python to list ut PIDs but it requires privileges, which am not sure how to do that by using the `subprocess` module.

`tcpview` and `tcpvcon` arent helpful either. Using `tcpvcon -a 443` for some reason returns nothing.

I am not sure if `psutil` module can help either, I know how to find a PID using it, but not sure how to find PIDs according to a specific port.

Is there any cross-platfrom way to do that? Maybe call a Bash script from python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, had to hardcode using `psutil` module.

```
import psutil
import sys

def get_pid():
    connections = psutil.net_connections()
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
    for con in connections:
        if con.raddr != tuple():
            if con.raddr.port == port:
                return con.pid, con.status
        if con.laddr != tuple():
            if con.laddr.port == port:
                return con.pid, con.status
    return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        pid = get_pid()
        if pid == -1:
            print(":: Not Found :<")
        else:
            print(f"Found service on Port {sys.argv[1]}")
            print(f"[+] PID: {pid[0]}")
            print(f"[+] Status: {pid[1]}")
            ch = input("Wanna Close: (y/n) ")
            if ch.lower() == 'y':
                p = psutil.Process(pid[0])
                p.terminate()
```

Comment: Note: psutil.net_connections is not working on Mac OS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124472/is-psutil-net-connections-unavailable-for-osx for more info.