# How do I resolve the "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" error?

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, serversocket

In Eclipse, I got this error:

```
run:
     [java] Error creating the server socket.
     [java] Oct 04, 2012 5:31:38 PM cascadas.ace.AceFactory bootstrap
     [java] SEVERE: Failed to create world : java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java] Java Result: -1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 10 seconds
```

I'm not sure why it came up  now, but it ran fine just a few hours ago. Do I need to restart my machine? How do i get to the bottom of it? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: I have seen this often on development machines when you are running trials of code -- How may the problem be avoided?

Comment: http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/changeglassfishport_4.1.aspx

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Yes you have another process bound to the same port.

[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) (Windows only) from [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals)  is my favorite app whenever I have a JVM_BIND error.  It shows which processes are listening on which port.  It also provides a convenient context menu to either kill the process or close the connection that is getting in the way.

Comment: a quick work around: Open server view > double click on the server > change the port numbers used (ie. for Tomcat admin, HTTP/1.1, & AJP/1.3)

Comment: @novice_developer `netstat` is the command you are looking for, with  -a and -p options, `man netstat` is your friend for all the rest :)

Comment: If the above process not working then restart the PC once, I think it will work. It started working in my case.

Answer (score 263):

If you know what port the process is running you can type: 
`lsof -i:<port>`.

For instance, `lsof -i:8080`, to list the process (pid) running on port 8080.

Then kill the process with `kill <pid>`

Comment: Yes, that's linux. Then try something equivalent in Windows. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/lsof-equivalent-for-windows

Comment: so I am using Raspbian and it says : bash: lsof : command not found. any suggestions?

Comment: @MonaJalal hmmm not sure but, maybe try something like `sudo apt-get install lsof`

Comment: @DiegoPino I am facing same error `java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)` 
I used `lsof -i:8080` and got `tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      106872/java` . What should I do ? Kill java ??

Comment: @AvijitBarua The process id (pid) of the java programm bound to this port is 106872. Every Java program that you launch presents itself as the program java (it is the java virtual machine that runs your compiled code). So yes, you could exit or kill this java program, if it is not some critical (system) tool, but your own program; have a look in a task manager like `htop`. Maybe you try to bind to a port used by a valid program that should not be killed.

Answer (score 146):

In windows

```
netstat -ano
```

will list all the protocols, ports and processes listening .
Use

```
taskkill -pid "proces to kill" /f
```

to kill the process listening to the port.
e.g

```
 taskkill -pid 431 /f
```

Comment: netstat -ano | find "number of your port"   Use this on Windows for specific port.

Comment: For me (using Windows 10) `find` didn't work but `findstr` did. To avoid false positives it also helps to prepend a colon, e.g. `netstat -ano | findstr :8080`. Having done this - let's say it returned a PID of 1234 - if you then want to look up the name of this process this can be done via `tasklist /fi "pid eq 1234`".

Answer (score 47):

In **Ubuntu/Unix** we can resolve this problem in 2 steps as described below.

1. Type `netstat -plten |grep java`

   This will give an output similar to:

   ```
   tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:8080   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1001  76084  9488/java
   ```

   Here `8080` is the port number at which the java process is listening and `9488` is its process id (pid).
2. In order to free the occupied port, we have to kill this process using the `kill` command.

   ```
   kill -9 9488
   ```

   `9488` is the process id from earlier. We use `-9` to force stop the process.

Your port should now be free and you can restart the server.

Comment: I am configuring CentOs server In digital ocean. If I kill this process how can I run server again ?

Comment: Only use -9 if it your own program and you don't have any data to lose there. It uncleanly kills the process, -15 tells the programm to exit itself.

Answer (score 43):

In Mac:

**Kill process**
Terminal: `kill <pid>`

**Find pid:**
Terminal: `lsof -i:<port>`

From Diego Pino answer

Comment: kill <pid> did not work on mac, 
kill -9 <PID> worked with me

Comment: kill -9 is force kill. You might try kill -15 which is sending TERM signal

Answer (score 36):

**(Windows Only)**

To kill a process you first need to find the Process Id (pid)

By running the command :

```
netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber
```

[image: As shown in picture below]

You will get your Process Id (PID), Now to kill the same process run this command:

```
taskkill /pid yourid /f
```

[image]

Comment: for powershell  1.) netstat -ano | findstr :5000
2.)Stop-Process <PID from step1>

Answer (score 21):

**For windows** :

1. **Find the process id**

   netstat -nao | find "8080"

It will show you the process ID as a number.

**Example**:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       18856
```

Here **18856** is the process ID

2. **Kill that process**

   taskkill /PID  18856 /F

**Output** : SUCCESS: The process with PID 18856 has been terminated.

Here using taskkill you are killing the process ID:18856

**For linux/Mac**:

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```

Here you find the process by port **8080** using `sudo lsof -t -i:8080` and killing it by sudo kill command

Answer (score 10):

For those who are looking for the **simplest of the answers** (as that is what we usually miss), just stop your running project and start it again.
Most of the time what we do is we forget to stop the project we ran earlier and when we re-run the project it shows such an issue.

I am also attaching a photo to make it clearer (I use 'Spring tool suite').
So what you need to do is either click the button on the extreme right, if you want to relaunch the same project or first click on the button which is 2nd from the right to stop your project and then the button on the extreme left to run your project. I hope this will solve the issue of few of the newer programmers. :)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You have another process running on the same port.

You could try killing one of the java.exe services running in your task manager - ps make sure you dont kill eclipse since that is listed as java.exe as well. If nothing else works, restarting your machine will fix it anyhow. It looks like youre not shutting down a socket from a previous test. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows CMD line, find out the Process ID that hold a connection on the bind port by entering following command:

C:> netstat -a -o

-a show all connections

-o show process identifier

And then **Terminate** the process.

Answer (score 5):

You need to close your port 
if you are a linux user then type

```
fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

Answer (score 4):

This BindException would come when another process is already running in the specified port(8080).

You can use anyone of the following approach.

1. **Change the server port:** If you are using Tomcat server and IntelliJ IDE, you can configure the server port by configuring the tomcat server

   [image]

or

- Go to tomcat>conf folder
- Edit server.xml
- Search "Connector port"
- Replace "8080" by your port number
- Restart tomcat server.

2. **Kill the existing running process in that port and start the server.**

> **For Linux/Mac**
>
> ```
> sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
> ```
>
> **For Windows**
>
> ```
> netstat -ano | findstr :8080
> taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F
> ```
>
> **Note:** (/F forcefully terminates the process)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as Guido Simone said it because another process listening to the same port.If you are in Ubuntu You can simply kill that process giving command
`sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:[port number])`

ex: `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)`

But once it didn't work for me.
i gave the command

```
$ lsof -i:[port]
```

and it shows nothing.

I checked my docker containers using command
`docker ps -a` but non of them alive.All containers has stopped
(but i remember ,i stopped one container which was used same port few minutes ago.).To make sure that docker is not the reason,I stop whole docker process using command `sudo service docker stop` and try again.
Surprisingly eclipse didn't show the error at that time .It run my program perfectly.

Hope my experience will help some one.

Answer (score 2):

The port is already being used by some other process as @Diego Pino said u can use lsof on unix to locate the process and kill the respective one, if you are on windows use netstat -ano to get all the pids of the process and the ports that everyone acquires. search for your intended port and kill.

to be very easy just restart your machine , if thats possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Restart the PC once, I think it will work. It started working in my case. One more thing can be done go to Task Manager and End the process.

[image: Screenshot for the reference.]

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Answer (score 2):

In my case Tomcat was running in a background. I've installed it as a external servlet while using Eclipse.
With a Spring Boot in Intellij it has it own server but cannot start while it's already occupied.
In my case Tomcat starts automatically I turn on my OS, that is why I need to shut down him manualy:

```
$ sudo service tomcat stop
```

of course "tomcat" depends what version of tomcat you are using. 

Hope it might help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in Eclipse when two consoles were opened when I started the Server program first and then the Client program. I used to stop the program in the single console thinking that it had closed the server, but it had only closed the client and not the server. I found running Java processes in my Task manager. This problem was solved by closing both Server and Client programs from their individual consoles(Eclipse shows console of latest active program). So when I started the Server program again, the port was again open to be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Your port must be busy in some Other Process. So you can download TCPView on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437 and kill the process for used port.

If you don't know your port, double click on the server that is not starting and click on Open Server Properties Page and click on glassfish from left column. You will find the ports here.

Answer (score 0):

(1) check the port is in use or not, kill that process

**$ lsof -i:[port]**

(2) another reason is the port is used by ipv6, solution:

edit **/etc/sysctl.conf**

add this to the file

**net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1**

then make it effect

**$ sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf**

or just reboot

Answer (score 0):

It means some other process is already using the port. In case if this port is being used by some other critical applications and you don't want to close that application, the better way is to choose any other port which is free to use.

Configure your application to use any other port which is free and you will see your application working.

Answer (score 0):

You can close every Java Process and start again your app:

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

start your app again...

Answer (score 0):

I actually just used the Terminate button in Console Tab. It's a small red box. Hope that hepls.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31519160)