# GlassFish Server Issue

Tags: java, glassfish

I am trying to add glass fish server and whenever i try to add that it gives me this exception and server shutdown

```
Severe: Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:237)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:86)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:184)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I delete the glass fish folder and downloaded again and try to connect but it keep giving me same error . I am using Glassfish 4 with Eclipse on Mac .

Comment: I think there is already an instance listening on the same port ?

Comment: Do you know how can i change or delete that instance ?

Comment: Yeah do `asadmin stop-domain domain1` where `domain1` is the name of your domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general way to kill any processes on Mac :

1.Find the pid using your port.

```
lsof -i:<port>
```

2.Then kill it using :

```
kill <pid>
```

Found the answer on :
[How do I resolve the “java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind)

Comment: to search port i went to this path install_dir/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml and searched for http-listener and my port is 28080 and when i use that port in lsof command it gives me nothing

Comment: Is this the new instance ? What about the https-listener ? And the admin-listener ?

Comment: <network-listeners>
          <network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="8181" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
        </network-listeners>

Comment: Sorry my typo even this is not resulting anything lsof -i:8080

Comment: Try 8181 and 4848 as well.

Comment: same nothing comes lsof -i:8181 lsof -i:4848

Comment: Since I'm not Mac expert, you might check for the right syntax of that `lsof` command. And you might need admin rights to execute it, so use `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in some cases, a painfully unhelpful error message from GlassFish.

Ordinarily it would mean that another process was bound to the port, as the other answer states, but the other reason this can happen is if the hostname does not resolve correctly.

Check what your Mac is named in `/etc/hostname` and how that compares to `/etc/hosts`. You may well need to make sure these match, e.g:

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/hostname 
mike-work
➜  ~ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mike-work
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `http-listener-1` (default **8080**) port and `http-listener-2` (default **8181**) to something different.

edit your domain.xml file usually in `(path to glassfish)/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` (remember to update your domainX accordingly)

```
<network-listeners>
    <network-listener protocol="http-listener-1" port="8080" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>
    <network-listener protocol="http-listener-2" port="8181" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>
    <network-listener protocol="admin-listener" port="4848" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>
</network-listeners>
```