# Cannot start Tomcat8 service java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, tomcat

When I try to run Tomcat8 service

```
service tomcat8 start
```

I get the following error message:

```
Job for tomcat8.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat8.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I see the following in /var/lib/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:339)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:737)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

However, when I run

```
fuser -n tcp 8080
```

I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to start and stop tomcat8 service. Please help.

Comment: You have either somehow configured 2 connectors so the server tries to listen twice or there is something using that port that isn't shown by `fuser`.

Comment: Do you see anything if you type http://localhost:8080 in your browser?

Comment: you can see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind/37626811#37626811

Comment: what are you using? windows or ubuntu?

Comment: kalkrin, yes , I see the Tomcat page.

Comment: Try going the Tomcat directory and running the stop script?

Comment: bharti rawat, I am using Ubuntu

Comment: kalkrin , on running ./shutdown.sh I get $CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted.

Comment: zapl I will look into that. I don't know how to configure connectors as yet

Comment: If you have another tomcat responding on 8080, then forget about that. You can try running `jps` which should show you all running java processes, then note the pid of it and kill it with `kill <pid>`.

Comment: zapl jps just outputs '14341 Jps'. kill 14341 says no such process.

Comment: even after running killall java I get the same error.