# Could not start Glassfish Server 4.1.1 http or https listener port is occupied while server is not running

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, listener, ports

every time i try to run my java project it immediatly stops and
 gives this error i tried changing my ports in the domain.xml section
 multiple times hoping id would work as the port i try first seem to be
 used but nothing helps.. anyone has an idea what could be the cause?
 here is my glassfish log:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
aug 12, 2016 12:10:35 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
aug 12, 2016 12:10:35 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
aug 12, 2016 12:10:35 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
aug 12, 2016 12:10:35 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@4125812e in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Ian Dessers\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/toetenbord/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/hoofdstuk%203/oef%201%20-lamp/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/hoofdstuk%205/oefening%201%20hfdstk%205/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/hoofdstuk%206/Oefening%201%20hoofdstuk%206/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/oefeningen%20voor%20examen/oef1hfstk2/build/web/
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 254ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   Java security manager is disabled.
Info:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Info:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Info:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Severe:   Error adding HttpProbes. NetworkListener http-listener-1s GrizzlyProxy is NULL
Info:   Created virtual server server
Info:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Info:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Info:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [examen_oef_hfstk2] at [/examen_oef_hfstk2]
Info:   Loading application examen_oef_hfstk2 done in 5.264 ms
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Downloads/Oefening1/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/Kleding_Dessers_Ian_r0640640/build/web/
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [jdbc_select_1_rij] at [/jdbc select 1 rij]
Info:   Loading application jdbc_select_1_rij done in 2.347 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [Dessers_Ian_r0640640_Cadeaubons] at [/Dessers_Ian_r0640640_Cadeaubons]
Info:   Loading application Dessers_Ian_r0640640_Cadeaubons done in 823 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [11_Berghmans_BeauStorylead_architectgreen] at [/11_Berghmans_BeauStorylead_architectgreen]
Info:   Loading application 11_Berghmans_BeauStorylead_architectgreen done in 2.033 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [dessers_ian_cadeaubons_bijles] at [/dessers_ian_cadeaubons_bijles]
Info:   Loading application dessers_ian_cadeaubons_bijles done in 1.077 ms
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (14.409ms), startup services(14.844ms), total(29.253ms)
Severe:   Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:237)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@446c3920 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@409986fe.
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@446c3920 from service registry.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Warning:   Internal Server error: /__asadmin/__locations
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:653)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOOutputStreamImpl.write(NIOOutputStreamImpl.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadImpl$Part.copy(PayloadImpl.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadImpl$Outbound.writeTo(PayloadImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:262)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Locally closed

Warning:   Unable to set customized error page
java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:465)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOWriterImpl.write(NIOWriterImpl.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.util.HtmlHelper.sendErrorPage(HtmlHelper.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:1358)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:1313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Locally closed

Info:   JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool]
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Info:   Shutdown procedure finished
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
aug 12, 2016 12:12:11 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
aug 12, 2016 12:12:11 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
aug 12, 2016 12:12:11 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
aug 12, 2016 12:12:11 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@79376098 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Ian Dessers\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/toetenbord/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/hoofdstuk%203/oef%201%20-lamp/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/hoofdstuk%205/oefening%201%20hfdstk%205/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/hoofdstuk%206/Oefening%201%20hoofdstuk%206/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/School%20ICT/Java/OEFS/oefeningen%20voor%20examen/oef1hfstk2/build/web/
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 240ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 25ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   Java security manager is disabled.
Info:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Info:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Info:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Severe:   Error adding HttpProbes. NetworkListener http-listener-1s GrizzlyProxy is NULL
Info:   Created virtual server server
Info:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Info:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Info:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [examen_oef_hfstk2] at [/examen_oef_hfstk2]
Info:   Loading application examen_oef_hfstk2 done in 2.956 ms
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Downloads/Oefening1/build/web/
Severe:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Ian%20Dessers/Desktop/Kleding_Dessers_Ian_r0640640/build/web/
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [jdbc_select_1_rij] at [/jdbc select 1 rij]
Info:   Loading application jdbc_select_1_rij done in 2.616 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [Dessers_Ian_r0640640_Cadeaubons] at [/Dessers_Ian_r0640640_Cadeaubons]
Info:   Loading application Dessers_Ian_r0640640_Cadeaubons done in 508 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [11_Berghmans_BeauStorylead_architectgreen] at [/11_Berghmans_BeauStorylead_architectgreen]
Info:   Loading application 11_Berghmans_BeauStorylead_architectgreen done in 1.283 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [dessers_ian_cadeaubons_bijles] at [/dessers_ian_cadeaubons_bijles]
Info:   Loading application dessers_ian_cadeaubons_bijles done in 918 ms
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (13.645ms), startup services(9.811ms), total(23.456ms)
Severe:   Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:237)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@446c3920 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@409986fe.
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@446c3920 from service registry.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Warning:   Internal Server error: /__asadmin/__locations
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:653)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOOutputStreamImpl.write(NIOOutputStreamImpl.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadImpl$Part.copy(PayloadImpl.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadImpl$Outbound.writeTo(PayloadImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:262)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Locally closed

Warning:   Unable to set customized error page
java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
```

Comment: Looks like other process occupied  your port, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind

Comment: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind". This log is enough to conclude that this port is already occupied

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar issue.. if you are using Netbeans and Windows This is how i resolved it

1. Go to Services..
2. click Server..
3. remove the glassfish server
4. Add Server
5. Select Glassfish server
6. change installation directory to C:/Program Files/glass-fish-4.1.1 (or locate the edition installed in your program files )
7. Or in another windows explorer locate C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config (note you should change the 4.1.1 to your current glassfish version or locate it from your system )
8. open domain.xml (with an editor preferably notepad++)
9. search for network-listener
10. change http port to any port number like like 8080 to 4949
    (you may chose to start asadmin from C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\bin  double click on asadmin.bat and run the command start-domain domain-1 it might show successful or failure)
11. save (or change notepad++ to give  admin privileges
12. go back to netbeans and start the glassfish under the services click servers and right click and start.. (if you cannot start the server try and run the web program , it will start the server , if its taking long  stop it get to service wait it will turn green then run it , it should work)

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you what worked for me, as I faced the same problem:

1. Open Services tab in your netbeans application (It was netbeans 8.2 for me).
2. After that Servers -> Glassfish Server 4.1.1.
3. Right click and select properties and see the http port written there(like 8080).
4. Open cmd.exe (win+r) and type netstat -ano. Then find the http port you have seen in previous step under local address.
5. See the pid code there and then open task manager and end that process having same pid code under details tab.
6. Run your program again (also add netbeans actions extension from chrome extensions, if not added. It was asked in my case.)

Answer (score 2):

I have solve this error by following steps:

- Goto service
- Add server
- Select glassfish server
- Next
- Next
- Domain 2 `// here I set domain name as domain2`
- Finish
- Restart netbeans
- Run that program which you wanted to learn

Answer (score 2):

If you're a Windows user my answer will really help you.

Step 1: Open the command line by pressing (windows + R) and type cmd there

Step 2: enter the command

```
netstat -aon | find ":8080" |find "LISTENING"
```

On entering this command you will see a set of port numbers and associated process IDs.

Step 3: Open the Task Manager --> details, there search for the process IDs which you saw in the command line.

Step 4: select those PIDs and click on End Task.

Now go to netbeans, the things will work fine.