# Binding server socket Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to create a Java program to send a message from client to Server and receive a response back using socket programming but it's coming up with this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:128)
>           at Bob.main(Bob.java:9)

client side:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1") ; //set the address of the server to be connected to. Any IP address can be set here as a string
    //If the name is saved in your "etc/hosts" file, then the name can be used instead of the ip address
    //Alternative method: InetAddress.getByAddress -see "stackoverflow" explanation if interested

    System.out.println("addr = " + addr);

    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 8080); //attempt to connect to the server by creating a socket using the IP address and Port number of the server

    try {
        System.out.println("socket = " + socket);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //create an input variable for the socket- accepts input from the socket

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true); // create an output variable for the socket- writes output to the socket

        //this loop simply writes to the socket 10 times waits for a reply from the socket and then prints the reply received
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            out.println("I am it: " + i); //write to socket
            String str = in.readLine(); //read from socket
            System.out.println(str);    //print to console line read from socket
        }

        out.println("END"); //send string that indicates end of transmission

    }catch( SocketException e ) {
        System.out.println("Server closed connection");
    }finally{
        System.out.println("closing...");
        socket.close(); //close the connection
    }
}
```

server side:

```
    public static final int PORT = 8080;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT); //create server socket object
    System.out.println("Started: " + s);

    try {
        Socket socket = s.accept(); //accept a socket connection using the Server Socket created previously
        try {
            System.out.println("Connection accepted: "+ socket);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //create an input variable for the socket- accepts input from the socket

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);   // create an output variable for the socket- writes output to the socket


            //this loop accepts input from the socket, prints out what it receives anc echoes it back into the socket until it recives the word "END" indicating the end of transmission
            while (true) {
                String str = in.readLine(); //read line from socket
                if (str.equals("END")) break;
                System.out.println("Echoing: " + str);  //print line to console
                out.println("You said: " + str); //echo line read back into socket
            }


        }catch ( SocketException  e ) {
            System.out.println("Client closed connection");
        }finally{               //close the present connection
            System.out.println("closing...");
            socket.close();
        }

    }catch( SocketException e ){
        System.out.println("Server socket closed unexpectedly");
    }finally{               //close the server socket. i.e. stop listening for connections
        s.close();          //without this line, the server would continue waiting for another connection
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running it on the same machine? Client & Server portion use the same port.

Comment: yes I am running it on the same machine

Comment: This has nothing to do with connecting a client. It happens when you run the server. `SocketException` does not mean 'client closed connection', and you aren't checking  for end of stream, which does.

Answer (score 3):

`java.net.BindException` means that you're trying to bind to an already occupied port.

You either have two instances of you server running, or some other program is already using port 8080.

Comment: Changed port to 5050, but still give me same error

Comment: Are you running two instances? Kill the old server before starting the new one.

Comment: I only have one server running

Comment: Also, check out the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind

Comment: Fixed it thank you :)