# Kafka connect not working?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

While going through the apache official page

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

A text file is created as

`echo -e "foo\nbar" > test.txt`

And to use kakfa connect following command is used

`bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties`

But while above command gets executed it shows a message `kafka-connect stopped`

[image]

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Yes, already all the codes and page description is mentioned in the question along with problem screen shot for clearance @Rob Thank you

Comment: `Address already in use`... Not a Kafka problem. You're running something else that conflicts with it

Comment: @cricket_007 I killed the initial `test` topic created, deleted the offsets then started kafka again it is showing `WARN FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@652ce654: java.net.BindException: Address already in use` and `Kafka Connect stopped` . How to rectify this ?

Comment: You must stop the other process running on that port. I cannot tell you what that is based on the information provided. Your port is 8083 https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737392/2308683 You *could* change the Kafka Connect port... Look in the property files for 8083, and pick a different number like 8084

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698358/how-to-change-the-kafka-connect-port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the "kafka connect" component port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698358/how-to-change-the-kafka-connect-component-port)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something else is using the same port that Kafka Connect wants to use.

You can use `netstat -plnt` to identify the other program (you'll need to run it as `root` if the process is owned by a different user).

If you want to get Kafka Connect to use a different port, edit `config/connect-standalone.properties` to add:

```
rest.port=18083
```

Where `18083` is an available port.