# Apache Nifi - refused to connect to localhost error

Tags: apache-nifi

When I tried  to connect to Nifi UI using http://localhost:8080/nifi, i am getting below error

```
    org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:331)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:935)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:158)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:72)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:297)

2020-02-27 11:51:11,834 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2020-02-27 11:51:11,836 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@355ee205{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-02-27 11:51:11,837 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session node 0 Stopped scavenging
```

Can anyone suggest what is the cause of this issue?
Nifi version- 1.9.2,installed on windows machine

Here is the nifi status logs,

```
12:33:16.886 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.NotificationServiceManager - Found 0 service elements
12:33:16.896 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.NotificationServiceManager - Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []
12:33:16.897 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi - Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED
12:33:16.897 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi - Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED
12:33:16.898 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi - Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED
12:33:16.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Status File: 
12:33:16.900 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Properties: {pid=9724}
Failed to determine if Process 9724 is running; assuming that it is not
12:33:16.902 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Apache NiFi is not running
```

Comment: It means another process on the host holds opened server socket on 8080 port
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind

Answer (score 2):

The port use by nifi is already used by another process.
you can change web server port in `conf/nifi.properties`

Comment: I tried changing my port to 8090 which was not used by others,then also i am getting the same error.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you look at netstat -puant | grep 8080 ? and nifi status ?

Comment: Yes,here is the nifi status