# Spring boot address and port number issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I was looking for possible root cause of the problem reported here (SO thread) -  [Cannot start a Tomcat v9.0 server in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310709/cannot-start-a-tomcat-v9-0-server-in-eclipse).

While fiddling for above (unrelated to the thread above mentioned), accidentally, instead of

```
server.port=8080
```

I put below in my application.properties file

```
server.address=8080
```

When I tried to start server I kept getting this error before I realized the typo.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use
```

When I replaced "address" with "port", all worked fine.

**Question:** Is it expected behavior or a known defect or a possible new defect? If its a new defect, where can I report it on Spring Community?

**UPDATE**

Per the comments on github issue tracker https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21101,  it is fixed now and the fix will be released in next release 2.2.7

Comment: `server.address` value should be an IP or hostname.

Comment: Agree Narendra but there should be some good handling on this. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot was unable to bind the server to the invalid address 8080.

And the default message is

> Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use

You can try to set

```
server.addresss=9090
```

and you will get the same message.

The error message is just misleading.

The message is generated in `PortInUseFailureAnalyzer`

And the PortInUseException is thrown here:

```
public void start() throws WebServerException {
    synchronized (this.monitor) {
        if (this.started) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors();
            Connector connector = this.tomcat.getConnector();
            if (connector != null && this.autoStart) {
                performDeferredLoadOnStartup();
            }
            checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted();
            this.started = true;
            logger.info("Tomcat started on port(s): " + getPortsDescription(true) + " with context path '"
                    + getContextPath() + "'");
        }
        catch (ConnectorStartFailedException ex) {
            stopSilently();
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (findBindException(ex) != null) {
                throw new PortInUseException(this.tomcat.getConnector().getPort());
            }
            throw new WebServerException("Unable to start embedded Tomcat server", ex);
        }
        finally {
            Context context = findContext();
            ContextBindings.unbindClassLoader(context, context.getNamingToken(), getClass().getClassLoader());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand Simon. But the question is address should not be treated as port. So can it be reported to Spring Community that it need to be fixed?

Comment: I just filed a bug report for that issue.https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21101 The point is that 8080 is a valid internet address so it may not be easy to fix

Comment: No but I'm teaching Spring Boot for a few years now at the university and had to look at the code many times already

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help in reporting it.