# How can I use sockets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I want to make a server and client program and transfer variables between they. I tried for a server program :

```
package testSocket;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("TEST SEVER");
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setSize(800, 600);
        
        try (ServerSocket sws = new ServerSocket(12480)) {
            Socket socket = sws.accept();
            
            OutputStream outs = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream douts = new DataOutputStream(outs);
            
            douts.writeUTF("Hello.");
            douts.close();
            outs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
        }
        
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
    }
    
}
```

And I tried for a client program :

```
package testSocket;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Socket tcs = new Socket("localhost", 12480);
        InputStream iss = tcs.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(iss);
        String str = new String(dis.readUTF());
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test" , str , JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        
        dis.close();
        iss.close();
        tcs.close();
        
    }
    
}
```

But the program did not work and gave the error :

```
Exception : java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
```

How can I solve this error ? Can you recommend anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have something already running on that port. Either kill it or change the port number in your program.

Comment: Maybe you already had a instance of that program running?

Comment: I tried on different ports but it did not work, all gave the same error

Comment: It gave the same error when I run it for the first time

Comment: You most likely still have the same application running from a previous start in your IDE. Either find the old run and kill it or restart your IDE, which should do the same thing.

Comment: It is also possible that an other application uses the port. I had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers, and although it doesn't list the port you use it is still possible.

Comment: I tried that too but this time client did not write "str" ​​variable, just wrote test on option pane @fish

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve the "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM\_Bind" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind)

Comment: I looked it from that site, 12480 is not used @tibetiroka

Comment: Maybe you can try restarting your computer or changing the port and check if the error still appears

Comment: I've tried both of them, but it's the same. Do I need to open a port for this kind programs?

Comment: No, java should do that by itself when you create a new server socket.

Comment: Could there be something missing in my program?

Comment: Maybe, but it can't be relevant. You try to create the server socket with the port, and it throws an error. There is no other actions needed before you crete the socket, and anything after that is irrelevant.

Comment: Are there other ways to create a server socket? if there are I try to use them, maybe it works

Comment: I think they all use the same methods in the background, at least within the standard library. (although maybe SSL sockets are different, not sure)

Comment: I made a few changes, it no longer gives the error but works incompletely. It was supposed to write "test hello" in joptionpane opened in client program , and the string "hello" from server. but it just says "test". Could this be related to this issue, or is the socket working but there is an error while receiving variables?