# WSO2 APImanager : Address already in use exception when starting

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

```
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,385]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Developer Portal Default Context : https://localhost:9443/devportal
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,385]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : https://localhost:9443/publisher
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,422]  INFO - EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker Execution plan: carbon.super_resource_50KPerMin_default saved in the filesystem
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,455]  INFO - EventJunction Producer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.throttle.globalThrottle.stream:1.1.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,455]  INFO - EventJunction Consumer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.throttle.processed.request.stream:1.0.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,455]  INFO - EventProcessorDeployer Execution plan is deployed successfully and in active state  : carbon.super_resource_50KPerMin_default
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,493]  INFO - EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker Execution plan: carbon.super_resource_20KPerMin_default saved in the filesystem
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,514]  INFO - EventJunction Producer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.throttle.globalThrottle.stream:1.1.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,514]  INFO - EventJunction Consumer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.throttle.processed.request.stream:1.0.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,514]  INFO - EventProcessorDeployer Execution plan is deployed successfully and in active state  : carbon.super_resource_20KPerMin_default
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,526]  INFO - EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker Execution plan: carbon.super_resource_10KPerMin_default saved in the filesystem
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,548]  INFO - EventJunction Producer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.throttle.globalThrottle.stream:1.1.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,548]  INFO - EventJunction Consumer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.throttle.processed.request.stream:1.0.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,548]  INFO - EventProcessorDeployer Execution plan is deployed successfully and in active state  : carbon.super_resource_10KPerMin_default
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,994]  INFO - CommonUtil Creation of folder is successful. Directory Name : AlertService-1.0.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:00,995]  INFO - CommonUtil Creation of folder is successful. Directory Name : Definitions
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : asyncWebhooksData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#asyncWebhooksData
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : cacheInvalidation of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#cacheInvalidation
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : keyManager of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#keyManager
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : throttleData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#throttleData
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : tokenRevocation of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#tokenRevocation
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : throttleData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#throttleData
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,093]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,096]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,197]  INFO - InMemoryAPIDeployer Deploying synapse artifacts of hello_mock
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,216]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : 03aaedcf-d24d-4869-b176-7f442b30875a was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,220]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : hello_mock--v1.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,222]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : hello_mock--v1.0.0_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,354]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : hello_mock:v1.0.0 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,354]  INFO - API {api:hello_mock:v1.0.0} Initializing API: hello_mock:v1.0.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,365]  INFO - InMemoryAPIDeployer Deploying synapse artifacts of AlertService
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,366]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : 46e7e883-ffe3-4550-a32a-26164b254e16 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,367]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : AlertService--v1.0.0_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,441]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : AlertService:v1.0.0 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,441]  INFO - API {api:AlertService:v1.0.0} Initializing API: AlertService:v1.0.0
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,448]  INFO - GatewayStartupListener Synapse Artifacts deployed Successfully in the Gateway
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,449]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender PassThroughHttpSender reloading SSL Config..
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,449]  INFO - PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener PassThroughHttpListener reloading SSL Config..
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,453]  INFO - ServerConnFactoryBuilder SSLProfile configuration is loaded from path: K:\repos\wso2\wso2am-4.2.0\repository/resources/security/listenerprofiles.xml
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,453]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder customSSLProfiles configuration is loaded from path: K:\repos\wso2\wso2am-4.2.0\repository/resources/security/sslprofiles.xml
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,453]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading custom SSL profiles for the HTTPS sender
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,456]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Custom SSL profiles initialized for 1 servers
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,456]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender updated with Dynamic Configuration Updates ...
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,463]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,463]  INFO - PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener HTTPS Reloaded
[2024-02-27 16:36:01,464]  WARN - PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener System may be unstable: HTTPS ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:89) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processSessionRequests(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:243) ~[httpcore-nio_4.4.16.wso2v1_4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:144) ~[httpcore-nio_4.4.16.wso2v1_4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) ~[httpcore-nio_4.4.16.wso2v1_4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager$1.run(PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager.java:561) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_4.0.0.wso2v20_12.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

Address already in use when starting API Manager 4.2.0.
Windows 11 ,Java 17

Checking process that is using port 8243

```
netstat -aof | findstr :8243
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8243           LAPTOP-QEV3B5TM:0      LISTENING       16680
```

`java.exe running pid:16680 mem:1.498.248K`

So it looks like the process that is using the port is the API manager itself. Should I change something in the configuration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve the "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM\_Bind" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind)

Answer (score 0):

8243 is the port that the api-manager's gateway runs on, if it's already in use I'd suggest you kill the process running in that port before starting up the api manager.