Error in Launching Ktor application with configuration server parameters in Code
I create a ktor project with configuration server parameters in Code
Here is my code
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("Hello World!")
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}

And build.gradle
val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_version: String by project
val logback_version: String by project

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1"
application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")

    val isDevelopment: Boolean = project.ext.has("development")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=$isDevelopment")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
}

It gives an error when starting
2024-07-06 21:08:19.851 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
2024-07-06 21:08:19.896 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Application auto-reloaded in 0.043 seconds.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:550)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:249)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda-1$lambda-0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:263)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


I tried to synchronize gradle
I couldn't find any information on the internet

I think things are in Run/Debug Configuration

I suggest looking into https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737392/13963150
