# How to find out which process is using a file in Java?

Tags: java, file, process, move

I'm trying to move a file from one dir to another in Java, but I got the following error message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

How can I find out which process is using this file in Java ?

I'm on Win 7.

Comment: Theres no platform-neutral, Java specific way of doing that (afaik).

Comment: Do you specifically need to do this from Java, or is a command-line approach suitable?  If so, which platform?

Comment: see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If a command-line approach is viable, and you're on a Linux-like system, then [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) is your friend.  There are about 10 gazillion flags for `lsof`, but for your needs, it should be as simple as:

```
lsof myfile
```

You should get output similar to the following:

```
COMMAND    PID    USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE    NODE NAME
someprog   4660 foobar mem    REG  253,0 58400 4522314 myfile
```

**EDIT**

You say you're using Windows.  I'm not familiar with Windows command-line tools.  However, here's a question that may help: *[How can I determine whether a specific file is open in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/lsof-equivalent-for-windows)*.