# PoolingClientConnectionManager setMaxTotal : what is a good default value to use?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

When using the Apache PoolingClientConnectionManager such as:

```
PoolingClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(???);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
```

What is considered a good default value to place there?
An example on the [Apache site here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java) uses `100` and elsewhere (stackoverflow.com/questions/13310490/apache-defaulthttpclient-how-to-set-max-total-connection-and-default-max-conn) I read that one should know roughly what the peak load will be and set it to that.

**So is there a good default value to place in `setMaxTotal(???)`?** Or is it recommended to figure our what your peak is and base it off that?

If the latter, **what's a good way of determining what your peak load is?**
I looked *[here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/was/7.0/ProblemDetermination/WA5721G10_ConnectionPool_edited/player.html)* through this slideshow and saw that the default is `10`, though you can set it to `0` and just let the good times roll (although that apparently negates any time out services, any good reasons for that?). I also happened to glance through the oracle docs (docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm) and saw some good tips on maintaining Connection Pools but nothing on determining the peak load.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always recommended to **figure out your peak load is and set the value accordingly**.

I also came across such a situation earlier. Dint find a proper way to get a good value for setMaxTotal().

But it worked out for me like this

You can do an `lsof -p <process id>` if your application is running on linux .

This will get you all the open connections from the application . 
And you can grep your target server name during heavy load.

```
lsof -p <process id>|grep <target server>
```

This will display all the connections to the target server from your application .

If httpclient will not cater heavy load , its always good to keep this value under 100. 
Pool will hold a maximum of only 100 objects.

Comment: I'm not running linux at the moment, so for anyone else who comes here and is also running windows, those commands do have windows equivalents - you can see [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-file-is-open-in-windows)