# Is there a way in Perl to tell if a Perl process in Windows is using a specific file?

Tags: perl, activestate, windows-process

Background information:

I have a Perl script converted to a EXE file, script.exe, that runs on Windows. Script.exe reads and will update at times to/from a configuration file, *config.ini*.

Script.exe is either executed with a command-line argument specifying location of the *config.ini* file. Or it can be run without a command-line argument and will default to the default location for the *config.ini* file.

Goal:

Prevent script.exe from being executed more than once using the same *config.ini* file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Am I reading it wrong, or are you simply looking for `flock`?

Comment: does `flock` work under windows?

Comment: @mpapec, Yes, though it creates mandatory locks rather than advisory locks

Comment: perhaps perl can read from Process Explorer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-file-is-open-in-windows

Comment: @ikegami ok, and all combinations work? excl/shared | blocking/nonblocking?

Comment: @mpapec, Yes. Technically, Windows even has another level of sharing flock can't control (delete).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`flock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) on the config file.

```
use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX LOCK_NB );

open(my $config_fh, '<', $config_qfn)
   or die("Can't open config file \"$config_qfn\": $!\n");

if (!flock($config_fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
   if ($!{EWOULDBLOCK}) {
      die("Config file $config_qfn already in use\n");
   }

   die("Error trying to lock the config file: $!\n");
}

... # Rest of program. Don't close $config_fh
```

Comment: he wants to prevent multiple PID from using same config, so LOCK_EX seems right choice.

Comment: @mpapec, Herp derp. Fixed.

Comment: @mpapec, `man 2 flock`. You might also want to look at `%!` in perlvar.

Comment: +1. ok, so everything that works regarding flock on ext3/linux is portable to win?