# Android: trouble updating Android SDK tools revision 22.3

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-4.4-kitkat

I hadn't updated my DK tools in Eclipse for quite some time, so I decided to do so today. Everything updated and installed just fine except for both SDK Tools and Platform-Tools for API 19 (Kit-Kat). I got a message saying that the platform-tools directory is being accessed and can't be renamed by the updater. I've been troubleshooting for a while, temporarily disabling applications on my computer, but to no avail. If you have any suggestions as to what could be accessing this folder (besides eclipse...), please post them here. I'm sure there are others that have the same issue.

The exact warning message reads:

> Failed to rename directory C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the SDK Manager "as administrator" ?

Following steps to run SDK manager as administrator on windows 7

1.Right Click SDK Manager

2.Select Run As Administrator

3.Click the YES button (if asked for)

does this work?

try this...

Extracted from :[here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4410#c38)

INSTRUCTIONS:

1.make a copy of the platform-tools directory and call this new directory tools2.

2.DO NOT USE 'SDK Setup.exe'.

3.Instead open up a cmd.exe window as administrator and run the following from this new tools2 directory (obviously the full path on your local machine will be different): J:\android-sdk-windows>tools2\android.bat update sdk

Basically, as noted before in this thread, 'SDK Setup.exe' invokes tools\android.bat, which makes it impossible for it to rename the tools directory thereafter. It's a bit goofy and should never have passed QA validation..

Comment: I thought it would, but that doesn't work. It must be some hidden application that's accessing it...

Comment: see my edited answer..hope this time this will work..:)

Comment: It doesn't work because platform-tools does not have an android.bat file in it. Only the tools directory has one. Regardless, I followed the steps with the contents of the tools folder, but I got the same error message. I truly believe that some hidden app is accessing this folder, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: just check this .... whether all this dependencies you have in place..http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html

Comment: No problems with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses the Android SDK Manager to install new SDK tools.
The Android SDK Manager resides in the android-sdk.
So you are trying to rename a directory while running an application whithin the path
that you are trying to rename. I am personally not into Windows, but due to the fact how windows handels its file access this could be a cause of your error message.
Still this error is very unconvenient, so at least you should give the Android SDK Manager without Eclipse a try. It can be executed by SDK Manager.exe (see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).
Ups, sorry @nitesh goel I saw your answer while posting, so this is a bit of a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah I ran the .exe as an administrator and that didn't work.

Comment: Well, here you can see some tools providing informations for open files on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-file-is-open-in-windows perhaps this will give you an entry point to further diagnostics