# How to unstage a deleted file in git

Tags: bash, git, github

I realize this question has been answered in other threads. However, my issue (I believe) is unique.

**Backstory:** I am a git bash noob. I only recently started using it, and as a result, have done quite a few dumb things. I create a test file, `AWACSfile.txt`, staged it with `git add`. I then did `git commit`, and here is where the problems started.

It brought up a new screen & prompted me for notes (or some other requirement when staging) that I did not add to the `commit` line. At that point, I didn't know what to do and ***attempted to exit the bash shell.***

It gave me a warning saying processes were still open. I ignored it, assuming that they would terminate when I exited the shell. ***Wrong***. Following that, I was unable to merge branches, switch branches, I could not delete the file, I could not unstage the file, I cannot do anything really without it giving me the attached error:[image]

I attempted to delete the `index.lock` file as well, but same error was met. I'm at a point where I have no idea what to do - I even tried uninstalling & it wouldn't uninstall because the process is still open with no force kill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *It gave me a warning saying processes were still open. I ignored it, assuming that they would terminate when I exited the shell. Wrong.*

[Windows has mandatory file locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows), meaning if a process has a file open you cannot delete it. Something is holding onto `index.lock` and shutting down the shell might not kill it.

Without seeing your previous Git history I can't say what that process might be. It could be any number of things which use `index.lock` hanging. An editor process used by `git commit` could be the culprit. You could [find the process which is holding `index.lock` open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-file-is-open-in-windows) and kill it.

Or you can try turning it off and on again: ie. restart your computer to ensure any hanging processes are stopped.