# Cygwin for windows is hanging when using "ls -l"

Tags: bash, cygwin, ls

Using Cygwin on Windows, I seem to be having an issue where using `ls -l` hangs for an abnormal amount of time, whereas using *ls* without the list argument, returns in almost no time at all.

```
[664] / *> which ls
/usr/bin/ls

[665] ~ *> time ls 1> /dev/null

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s

[666] ~ *> time ls -l 1> /dev/null

real    0m10.836s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.077s
```

What might be the cause / fix for this? How can I investigate (why) this is taking so much time? This only seems to happen in my `%HOME%` directory, all other locations seem to be instant.

Comment: I'd be looking to see if there's anything different about that directory, mount/junction points and such, or strange files. By the way, `-l` is "long" format, not "list".

Comment: Check which processes are working on your %HOME% and may cause disk contention, to see how visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-file-is-open-in-windows#188337

Comment: Is your cygwin home directory on a network drive? Are you connected to a domain? You may need to set up a cygwin server to cache a large domain users list.

Comment: Yes domain, but my user director should be local?

Answer (score 1):

`-l` causes *ls* to convert numbers into usernames, involving long lookup times in a big domain.

I highly recommend running *cygserver*. This has a number of benefits over and above the speed increase.

I once posted an answer to a related question on Stack Overflow, but it was migrated to SuperUser. So, rather unhelpfully, my suggestion is to go and look at [my answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1183283).

Comment: Oooohhhhh, this actually seems to be the most plausible cause, good locks, will dive into this today :)